# X-position of Sankey nodes in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

[This is my Sankey diagram showing the attrition of sexual assault cases that are reported to the police in New Zealand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cp9j.png)

[This is the data I am drawing from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fl4lx.png)

Because it's a diagram to show attrition; I want to the nodes to stack vertically so that there should only be 3 nodes on the far right, and at each level of the process, the nodes should stack on top of one another. I can't figure out why they are all clustering on the right.

I think the issue is in the computeNodeBreaths function of the plugin I am using, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

function computeNodeBreadths() {
    var remainingNodes = nodes,
        nextNodes,
        x = 0;

```
while (remainingNodes.length) {
  nextNodes = [];
  remainingNodes.forEach(function(node) {
    node.x = x;
    node.dx = nodeWidth;
    node.sourceLinks.forEach(function(link) {
      if (nextNodes.indexOf(link.target) < 0) {
        nextNodes.push(link.target);
      }
    });
  });
  remainingNodes = nextNodes;
  ++x;
}
```

Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Thanks